# Why received images from API give 500 error but the rest of the data is correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a strange problem that in the Next.js project that I am going to run. When I take a photo of the API project for the URL, it gives an error of 500, but it receives other data such as price without any error.

This is the `fetchApi` file:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const baseUrl = "https://bayut.p.rapidapi.com";

export const fetchApi = async (url) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "bayut.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "ab9d289155mshc78dae64ad21407p17222bjsnb2a155e6d666",
    },
  });

  return data;
};
```

This is index file I generate the home page here and get the API via `getStaticProps` and generate the items in the property folder.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Flex, Box, Text, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';

import Property from '../component/Property';
import { baseUrl, fetchApi } from '../utils/fetchApi';

export const Banner = ({ purpose, title1, title2, desc1, desc2, buttonText, linkName, imageUrl }) => (
  <Flex flexWrap='wrap' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center' m='10'>
    <Image src={imageUrl} width={500} height={300} />
    <Box p='5'>
      <Text color='gray.500' fontSize='sm' fontWeight='medium'>{purpose}</Text>
      <Text fontSize='3xl' fontWeight='bold'>{title1}<br />{title2}</Text>
      <Text fontSize='lg' paddingTop='3' paddingBottom='3' color='gray.700'>{desc1}<br />{desc2}</Text>
      <Button fontSize='xl' bg="blue.300" color="white">
        <Link href={linkName}><a>{buttonText}</a></Link>
      </Button>
    </Box>
  </Flex>
);

const Home = ({ propertiesForSale, propertiesForRent }) => (
  <Box>
    <Banner
      purpose='RENT A HOME'
      title1='Rental Homes for'
      title2='Everyone'
      desc1=' Explore from Apartments, builder floors, villas'
      desc2='and more'
      buttonText='Explore Renting'
      linkName='/search?purpose=for-rent'
      imageUrl='https://bayut-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image/145426814/33973352624c48628e41f2ec460faba4'
    />
    <Flex flexWrap='wrap'>
      {propertiesForRent.map((property) => <Property property={property} key={property.id} />)}
    </Flex>
    <Banner
      purpose='BUY A HOME'
      title1=' Find, Buy & Own Your'
      title2='Dream Home'
      desc1=' Explore from Apartments, land, builder floors,'
      desc2=' villas and more'
      buttonText='Explore Buying'
      linkName='/search?purpose=for-sale'
      imageUrl='https://bayut-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image/110993385/6a070e8e1bae4f7d8c1429bc303d2008'
    />
    <Flex flexWrap='wrap'>
      {propertiesForSale.map((property) => <Property property={property} key={property.id} />)}
    </Flex>
  </Box>
);

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const propertyForSale = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=25`);
  const propertyForRent = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-rent&hitsPerPage=25`);

  return {
    props: {
      propertiesForSale: propertyForSale?.hits,
      propertiesForRent: propertyForRent?.hits,
    },
  };
}

export default Home;
```

This is property file.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Box, Flex, Text } from '@chakra-ui/layout';
import { Avatar } from '@chakra-ui/avatar';
import { FaBed, FaBath } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { BsGridFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { GoVerified } from 'react-icons/go';
import millify from 'millify';

import DefaultImage from '../assets/images/house.jpg';

const Property = ({ property: { coverPhoto, price, rentFrequency, rooms, title, baths, area, agency, isVerified, externalID  } }) => (
  <Link href={`/property/${externalID}`} passHref>
    <Flex flexWrap='wrap' w='420px' p='5' paddingTop='0px' justifyContent='flex-start' cursor='pointer' >
      <Box>
        <Image src={coverPhoto.url} width={400} height={260} />
      </Box>
      <Box w='full'>
        <Flex paddingTop='2' alignItems='center' justifyContent='space-between'>
          <Flex alignItems='center'>
            <Box paddingRight='3' color='green.400'>{isVerified && <GoVerified />}</Box>
            <Text fontWeight='bold' fontSize='lg'>AED {price}{rentFrequency && `/${rentFrequency}`}</Text>
          </Flex>
          <Box>
            <Avatar size='sm' src={agency?.logo?.url}></Avatar>
          </Box>
        </Flex>
        <Flex alignItems='center' p='1' justifyContent='space-between' w='250px' color='blue.400'>
          {rooms}
          <FaBed /> | {baths} <FaBath /> | {millify(area)} sqft <BsGridFill />
        </Flex>
        <Text fontSize='lg'>
          {title.length > 30 ? title.substring(0, 30) + '...' : title}
        </Text>
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  </Link>
);

export default Property;
```

It is really strange that it receives all the information correctly from the server, except for the photo. Do you have a solution?

Comment: If that's your real API key you're show here, you might want to obscure it.

Comment: Please add what the network tab says when Image request is made? the image link `https://bayut-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image/145426814/33973352624c48628e41f2ec460faba4` seems to open on a new tab

Comment: https://bayut.p.rapidapi.com/properties/list?locationExternalIDs=5002&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=25

Comment: this is main Api

Comment: headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "bayut.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "ab9d289155mshc78dae64ad21407p17222bjsnb2a155e6d666",
    },

Comment: i giv this api from https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/bayut

Comment: Have you configured the remote domain of the images URL in `next.config.js`? See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#domains for details.

Comment: @ juliomalves yes i did

Answer (score 0):

For Me, when this happens, I just change the self closing `image` tag to a proper closing one.

So you should try changing

```
<Image src={coverPhoto.url} width={400} height={260} />
```

to

```
<Image src={coverPhoto.url} width={400} height={260}></Image>
```

, and do the same for your banner object.

I do not know if this is the proper way to do this, but it works for me

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work properly

Comment: It's very strange to me. I did the same thing in the project] react.